# Deploy support files from secondary assembly

Tags: windows-runtime

I'm, porting a phone application written using MVVMCross to Windows RT. The application uses SQLite and has a database that is not empty at deploy so I want it to be packaged in the installation folder anc copied to LacalFolder when the application starts.

The database really belongs to the "Core" assembly shared between phone and WinRT but if I put the file in the Core project (in a custom directory called Data), define it as Content and set the Copy Always flag the file does not get copied to the application installation folder.

If I put the file in a directory under the UI project the file gets copied as expected. Any suggestion to avoid keeping two files for the same resource (and the troubles this will cause) ?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 8 WinRT projects by default use the Content type which does loose packing of files (they are not included in the assembly). If your Core assembly is part of your solution as a project - VS will properly package it copying all the content to the "Core" subfolder of the appx. If you simply have the dll file referenced in your solution - the resource files will not be packaged. The solution in that case is to do something to get these additional files to deploy with the dll. One option is to package the dll as a .vsix together with the assets as described in Tim Heuer's [blog post](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/03/07/creating-custom-controls-for-metro-style-apps.aspx). Another is to do what you did and put the file in the app project. You can add the file to the app project "As Link" to avoid having a copy of the file - it makes Visual Studio create a sort of logical/symbolic link to the file instead of creating a copy - simply right click a folder in the Solution Explorer/app project, select "Add/Existing Item", browse to the file and instead of hitting the "Add" button - use the dropdown triangle on the button to select "Add As Link".

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, the link to the file worked as a viable solution. What puzzled me was, and still is, the fact that I've the Core library as a project in the solution not just the DLL reference. Everything gets copied (for example Core resources for MultiLanguage support) but not the db file.